# ORDER BY for JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to fetch the last message for a group of chats so that I can sort them by last updated.

Everything in my query works fine, except the message fetched is the first created message, not the last one.

Here is a sample from the query:

```
SELECT
dc.id AS chat,
dcp.*,
dcm.created AS last_message_created
FROM data_chats dc
INNER JOIN data_chats_parties dcp ON dcp.chat=dc.id
AND dcp.member=1 -- current users id
AND dcp.status >= 1
INNER JOIN data_chats_messages dcm ON dcm.chat=dc.id AND dcm.active=1
WHERE dc.active=1
GROUP BY dcp.chat 
ORDER BY dcm.created DESC
```

Is there anyway I can sort the results from the `data_chats_messages` by the `created` column?

Comment: use...order by data_chats_messages.created desc

Comment: That will limit all the returned rows. I am fetching many chats with this query.

Comment: Can you show some sample data?  `ORDER BY last_message_created DESC` should give the most recent created date first.

Comment: I only want the last message for each chat. Many chats are fetched, but only one message per chat, the last message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This one.This work in all db

```
 SELECT
 dc.id AS chat,
 dcp.*,
 dcm.created AS last_message_created
 FROM data_chats dc
 INNER JOIN data_chats_parties dcp ON dcp.chat=dc.id
 AND dcp.member=1 -- current users id
 AND dcp.status >= 1
 INNER JOIN (select * from data_chats_messages order by created desc) dcm ON dcm.chat=dc.id AND dcm.active=1
 WHERE dc.active=1
 GROUP BY dcp.chat 
 ORDER BY dc.id DESC
```

> This will also work but not in all db .
>
> it is not known to work in mariadb 5.5

```
 select * from (SELECT
    data_chats.id AS chat,
    data_chats_parties.*,
    data_chats_messages.created AS last_message_created
  FROM data_chats
    INNER JOIN data_chats_parties
        ON data_chats_parties.chat=data_chats.id
            AND data_chats_parties.member=1 -- current users id
            AND data_chats_parties.status >= 1
    INNER JOIN data_chats_messages ON data_chats_messages.chat=data_chats.id AND data_chats_messages.active=1
  WHERE
    data_chats.active=1
  ORDER BY last_message_created DESC) a  GROUP BY chat
```

Comment: Was trying to avoid that because it will be slow on a large scale. Would you suggest changing the db structure instead?

Comment: what is the datatype of `data_chats_messages.created` in db? is it  a timestamp?

Comment: Yes created column is a timestamp. Thank you for the answer. Am I wrong that inner selects like this are a big resource hog?